# How to fix this problem of while loop in the factorial procedure>

Tags: python, factorial

I try to define a factorial procedure with these codes, but the result I get is the n^2, not n*(n-1)*(n-2)......*1. It seems the i*n has only been implemented once when i=n. I am confused and What is the problem?

```
def factorial(n):           
    i = 1
    while n >=i:
        result = i * n
        i = i + 1
    return result
```

Comment: I try to define a factorial procedure with these codes, but the result I get is the n^2, not n*(n-1)*(n-2)......*1. It seems the i*n has only been implemented once when i=n. I am confused and What is the problem?

Comment: You repeatedly overwrite the value of result with the current calculation.

Comment: `result = result * i`

Comment: This is a logic question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep aggregating the operation over `result` instead:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    while n > 1:
        result *= n
        n -= 1
    return result
```

so that `factorial(4)` returns: `24`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my problem!!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter your logic, see @blhsing' answer.

An easier way to implement factorial is like so:

```
def factorial(n):
    if not n:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

Remember that `math.factorial` also exists. This is the best solution you're not required to build the function yourself.